# Is it worth moving from Spring Config Server with Git to AWS parameter Store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, configuration

We are planning to move some springboot (2.1.3) apps to AWS ECS. Currently we are setting application properties in a github repo and serving them through a Spring Cloud Config Server. All of these services are running on premises. I was wondering if we should stick to the cloud config server and the github repo as the back or maybe move to something else, like AWS parameter store.

Comment: How will configuration changes get into AWS Parameter Store? A human manually changing the configuration in AWS Parameter Store is an error prone process. With the configuration in Git, you can prepare a change in a pull request for review before applying. If something goes wrong, you can revert to a previous configuration in the Git history.

Comment: Right, good point, the question is not only about the technological perspective but also considering these aspects about management. Although want to believe AWS has it own mature change management process. So you would stick to the Config Server.